# extract datetime from a folder parth string

Tags: python

I have a list of files that are arranged in the following format:

```
'folder/sensor_01/2021/12/31/005_6_0.csv.gz', 
'folder/sensor_01/2022/01/01/005_0_0.csv.gz', 
'folder/sensor_01/2022/01/02/005_1_0.csv.gz', 
'folder/sensor_01/2022/01/03/005_4_0.csv.gz',
....
```

Now, what I want to do is filter the entries which are within the time range. So, in the folder listings, the middle segment after `sensor_01` and before `005` give the time entry (till date resolution).

I am getting stuck with how to extract this time segment from the folder path and convert it to a python DateTime object. I think I can then use the comparison operators to filter the entries.

Comment: Use regex. Take all of these as strings and do a regex match on them with grouping for what you want. Once you have a grouping, change tat to a date or datetime object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the string to DateTime formatting.

### Split

You can split the text to get the Year, Month, and Day part.

```
file = 'folder/sensor_01/2021/12/31/005_6_0.csv.gz'
file.split("/")
# ['folder', 'sensor_01', '2021', '12', '31', '005_6_0.csv.gz']
```

Here 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements are year, month and day.

Or

### strptime

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/2681662. You can create a DateTime object from a string. But there's no restriction of delimiters for the Year, Month, and Day separator.
So:

```
file = 'folder/sensor_01/2021/12/31/005_6_0.csv.gz'
datetime.strptime(file, 'folder/sensor_01/%Y/%m/%d/005_6_0.csv.gz') # This is valid
# datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done using regex.

`\S+\/sensor_[\d]+\/([\S\/]+)\/[\S_]+\.csv\.gz`

I have used this regex to match and group the date portion of one of the strings.

```
In [11]: import re

In [12]: string = 'folder/sensor_01/2021/12/31/005_6_0.csv.gz'

In [13]: reg = '\S+\/sensor_[\d]+\/([\S\/]+)\/[\S_]+\.csv\.gz'

In [15]: re.match(reg, string).groups()[0]
Out[15]: '2021/12/31'
```